# Using Custom Component as trigger in semantic-ui-react modal

Tags: javascript, reactjs, semantic-ui

I want to use the semantic UI react modal, but it requires a trigger, in all of the [examples in the documentation](https://react.semantic-ui.com/modules/modal), a button is a trigger.

I have created a card and I want to use that card as the trigger, how can I achieve this?

I also found this [issue on Github](https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI-React/issues/2487) to be useful but it did not work for me. The answer to this issue says we have to handle some unhandled props and I did that accordingly but still did not work. Could that be what I am handling wrong here?

Here's my code:
Created a card

```
import React from 'react';
import { Card, Icon } from 'semantic-ui-react'

export default class AddAssignmentCard extends React.Component {

  render() {
        const { ...rest } = this.props;
    return (
        <Card { ...rest }>
            <Card.Content textAlign="center" className="p-5">
                <Card.Meta>
                    <a>
                    <Icon name='plus' size="big" />
                    <h3 className="mt-1">Create Assignment</h3>
                  </a>
              </Card.Meta>
        </Card.Content>
        </Card>
    );
  }
}
```

And then using it as a trigger here:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Modal, Form, Button } from 'semantic-ui-react'
import AddAssignmentCard from './AddAssignmentCard';

export default class CreateAssignmentModal extends React.Component {
  state = {}

  render() {
    return (
        <Modal className="scrolling" size='tiny' trigger={<AddAssignmentCard {...this.props} />}>
            <Modal.Header>Create Assignment</Modal.Header>
            <Modal.Content>
                <Form>
                    <Form.Field>
                        <label>Title</label>
                        <input placeholder="Assignment Title" />
                    </Form.Field>
                </Form>
            </Modal.Content>
        </Modal>
    )
  }
}
```

And then rendering it like this:

```
<AddAssignmentCard {...this.props} />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did some tweaking and this finally worked for me. My mistake was that I was rendering the trigger instead of the modal.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Card, Icon } from 'semantic-ui-react'

export default class AddAssignmentCard extends React.Component {

  render() {
        const { ...rest } = this.props;
    return (
        <Card { ...rest }>
            <Card.Content textAlign="center" className="p-5">
                <Card.Meta>
                  <Icon name='plus' size="big" />
                  <h3 className="mt-1">Create Assignment</h3>
              </Card.Meta>
        </Card.Content>
        </Card>
    );
  }
}
```

Use the Card as trigger

```
import React from 'react';
import { Modal, Form, Button, Dropdown } from 'semantic-ui-react'
import AddAssignmentCard from './AddAssignmentCard';

export default class CreateAssignmentModal extends React.Component {
  state = {}

  render() {
    return (
        <Modal className="scrolling" size='tiny' trigger={<AddAssignmentCard {...this.props} />}>
            <Modal.Header>Create Assignment</Modal.Header>
            <Modal.Content>
                <Form>
                    <Form.Field>
                        <label>For which of your students? </label>
                        <Dropdown
                            fluid
                            options={[]}
                            search
                            selection
                            placeholder='Select Student'
                            noResultsMessage='You have no student yet.'
                        />
                    </Form.Field>
                    <Form.Field>
                        <label>Title</label>
                        <input placeholder="Assignment Title" />
                    </Form.Field>
                    <Form.TextArea label='Description' placeholder='Write the Assignment details here...' />
                </Form>
            </Modal.Content>
        </Modal>
    )
  }
}
```

And then render the modal like this

```
<CreateAssignmentModal {...this.props} />
```